# Полупрозрачность блока

Tags: css3, html

Как сделать блоки полностью полупрозрачными, один блок получилось сделать, а остальные два - нет.

[image]

Везде установил opacity:0.3. Но нормальный результат получился только в подвале. Вот код

```
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
body {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #999;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 15px;
}
h1 a,
li a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul li {
    list-style: none;
}
img {
    border: 0px;
}
#wrap {
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 1000px;
}
#header {
    background-color: white;
    width: 1000px;
}
#logo h1 {
    text-shadow: 3px 0px 7px grey;
}
#logo h1 a {
    color: #253aeb;
    font-size: 50px;
}
#logo sup a {
    color: red;
    font-size: 25px;
    text-shadow: none;
}
#header-menu {
    height: 50px;
    width: 1000px;
}
#header-menu ul {
    width: 100%;
}
#header-menu ul li {
    float: left;
    line-height: 50px;
    width: 150px;
}
#header-menu ul li a {
    color: black;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#header-menu ul li ul {
    display: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#header-menu ul li ul a {
    color: black;
}
#header-menu ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    left: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 75px;
}
```

Comment: Тут что форум экстрасенсов? Покажи код, как делал? Где не получается, какие это div и тд?

Comment: На jsfiddle, пожалуйста

Answer (score 1):

Используй лучше RGB с Альфа-каналом(rgba) намного мобильней чем opacity.